# Nonlinear ODE: Overdamped pendulum and sketching the relationship between $sin(\theta)(t)$ vs. $t$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, dynamical-systems, nonlinear-dynamics

I am looking at exercise 4.4.2 in Strogatz's *Nonlinear Dynamics and Chaos* book, but I am working through the book as a self-study. One of the questions deals with the equation for an  overdamped pendulum in section 4.4 of the book. The equation makes an assumption that the inertia term is negligible, so equation is:

$$
b\dot{\theta} + mgL\sin{\theta} = \Gamma
$$

Where $b, m, g, L, \Gamma$ are constants. The equation is further nondimensionalized to form

$$
\theta' = \gamma - \sin{\theta}
$$

where $\theta' = \frac{d\theta}{d\tau}$, where $\tau$ is dimensionless time. The actual constants are $\tau = \frac{mgL}{b}t$, and $\gamma = \frac{\Gamma}{mgL}$.

The question that is asked in the book is below.

[image: Strogatz 4.4.2]

I understand the equation well enough, but I was not clear on what is being asked for when they want a plot of $\sin{\theta}(t)$ versus $t$. Seems like this is a nonuniform oscillator, so when $\gamma < 1$ then there will be some stable and unstable fixed points, and the time behavior of the system will be fast and then slow progress towards the stable fixed points. If $\gamma = 1$ then you have some half-stable fixed points, so you have progress towards these fixed points over time with slight perturbations sending the system back into oscillation. But I was not sure if there was a more precise way to characterize these time behaviors using the equations? Would I need to reintroduce the dimensional time variable back into the equation to demonstrate the time behavior on the $t$ scale, or is there a better way?

Comment: The force $\Gamma$ represents an infinite rocket motor in tangential direction producing thrust from "the outside". There is no oscillation of the pendulum, it ever goes in one direction, only the projection on the horizontal axis goes back and forth. I would say to plot $\sin\theta$ vs. $\tau$, I think this is also the intent of the plotting task. That it is formulated using $t$ is some attempt to emphasize the "time" aspect, just presume (for the plots) that the constants are such that the scale factor to $\tau$ is $1$.

Comment: @LutzLehmann thanks for the info. Yes, that makes sense. The notation of $sin(\theta)(t)$ was confusing me, since it implied the dimensional time instead of non-dimensionalized time. But it should not make that much of a difference as you say.